# jQuery .animate() sets it's own initial value when animating width

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm working on an implementation for a sidebar that slides in from the left, squashing the main content div as it goes.

As you can see from the demo (http://jsfiddle.net/xy1x885n/), sliding out works fine but when it comes to sliding back in again the sidebar div is set to 100% width before the animation starts causing a very jarring effect. This is easier to see if you inspect the sidebar element and watch the width css property very carefully.

This has been observed on Chrome 43, IE 11 & FF Developer 40

HTML:

```
<button type="button" onClick="toggleSidebar();">Toggle</button>
<div id="sidebar-container">
    <div id="sidebar-side">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="sidebar-main">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#sidebar-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
#sidebar-side {
    float: left;
    display: none;
    background-color: #0bf;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#sidebar-main {
    float: right;
    background-color: #fb0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
.clear {
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function toggleSidebar() {
    var sidebar = $("#sidebar-side");
    var main = $("#sidebar-main");
    if (sidebar.hasClass("active")) {
        sidebar.stop().animate({
            opacity: 0,
            width: "0%"
        }, function () {
            sidebar.css('display', 'none');
        });
        main.stop().animate({
            width: "100%"
        });
    } else {
        sidebar.css('display', 'block');
        main.stop().animate({
            width: "60%"
        });
        sidebar.stop().animate({
            opacity: 1,
            width: "40%"
        });
    }
    sidebar.toggleClass("active");
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here / seeing things, or is jQuery really setting the width to 100% rather than just going from the initial width?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the width of the sidebar to `0` instead of `"0%"`:

```
sidebar.stop().animate({
    opacity: 0,
    width: 0
}, function(){
    sidebar.css('display', 'none');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xy1x885n/4/)

Comment: Genius! Thanks for that works like I charm. Do you know why this happens? If so can you please update your answer? (I'll accept it in 5 minutes when SO lets me).

Comment: I was trying to investigate why and honestly, I don't know. When setting the value as a string of `0%` the `div` starts the animation at a completely different width than it's initially set to. It's possibly a bug.

Comment: Thanks, I'll post it in the jQuery bug tracker and see what response I get.